# Automatically include conflicting-and-resolved files in a git merge commit message

Tags: git, merge, git-merge, git-merge-conflict

In the case of a git merge sometimes there are conflicts that must be resolved externally before the merge is complete. As these may represent 'areas of special interest', it would be be nice to call such out explicitly.

*Is there a way to ensure that all such files manually resolved are included in the resulting merge message?* (Preferably this would be done before the commit message editor is opened so that there is an available template/space to fill in with details.)

eg. the commit message might look like:

```
Merge remote-tracking branch .. into ..

Manually merged files:
- a.foo
- b.bar
```